# How can I make a button input as Integer

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, int

I just started to work with python with a little to no actual programming background. As most of the newcomers I am writing a calculator. I've got some buttons for writing my numbers into a label. This works well if I set the textvariable in StringVar as the snippet below:

```
numbers = StringVar()
display = Label(root, font = "Arial 20", textvariable = numbers, relief = RIDGE, anchor = E)
```

But when I set this into IntVar it doesnt work anymore. I don't seem to be able to solve my problem. Here is some more of my code to clearify what Im doing (wrong?).

```
numbers = IntVar()
display = Label(root, font = "Arial 20", textvariable = numbers, relief = RIDGE, anchor = E)
display.place(x=1, y=1, width=212,height=47


def display_input (inputValue):
    CurrentInput = numbers.get()
    numbers.set(CurrentInput + inputValue)


btn1 = Button(root, text = '1', bd = '1', bg = 'lightsteelblue', relief = RAISED, command = lambda: display_input('1'))
btn1.place(x=1, y=96, width=71,height=47)
```

Comment: Your question seems unclear. If you want to make a button input an integer, why are you passing in a string? Have you tried passing in an integer?

Comment: Why do you use `IntVar`?  `StringVar` is easier to concat the _digit_ represented by the clicked button.

Comment: @ Bryan. Yeah, I didnt realize I was passing these as a string in my buttons, now I know.

Comment: acw1668, I know that StringVar is easier and I actually used it that way now. For some functions, like math.sqrt, I needed my input to be an integer. While defining the function I used int() to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you are calling the `display_input` function with a string (`str`) instead of an integer (`int`):

```python
# '1' with quotes is a string, not an integer
Button(root, ..., command = lambda: display_input('1'))
```

This will make you attempt to update an `IntVar` with the result of the sum of an `int` with a `str`, which is not supported:

```python
>>> 0 + '1'
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Replacing that `command` with `display_input(1)` instead (here `1` is an `int`) should fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought it would be something quite simple that I overlooked, makes sense.